# Fill values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, concatenation

I have the following dataframes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, size=(5,5)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(2,2)))
```

When i do this, I have not problem:

```
df1.iloc[0:2,0:2] = df2
```

The result of this:

```
6  4  0  0  0
9  2  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
```

But when i try this:

```
df1.iloc[0:2,3:5] = df2
```

The result is this:

```
0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

How can I convert this NaN to df2?

Answer (score 1):

There is possible set `numpy array`, but is necessary same shape of `df2` with selection by `iloc`:

```
print (df1.iloc[0:2,0:2].shape)
(2, 2)
print (df2.shape)
(2, 2)

df1.iloc[0:2,3:5] = df2.values
print (df1)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  0  8  5
1  0  0  0  0  4
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
```